# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec| Error during installation of pip python-stdnum==1.8

Tags: python, windows, pip, package, decode

I am fairly new to programming, so please bear with me.

While I was installing some required packages for a module that I'm using, I wasn't able to install `python-stdnum==1.8`.

I got the following error message:

```
File "C:\Users\59996\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 967: character maps to <undefined>
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Is there anything I can do to still be able to install the package?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23):

If it's for the Odoo 14 install on Windows, the issue is in the "requirements.txt"

Change "python-stdnum==1.8" to "python-stdnum==1.8.1" (even if the answer of Federico Baù is working by the way)

then another issue will appear so change "psutil==5.6.6" to "psutil==5.6.7"
still in the "requirements.txt"

source: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/62919

Best regards

Comment: you're a lifesaver man, but in my case psutil version 5.6.7 is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I ran to the same problem while installing Odoo Dependencies in Windows, but after some tacke I found a solution.

It's a old bug with `stdnum 1.8`  --> [stdnum 1.8 installation fails on windows](https://github.com/arthurdejong/python-stdnum/issues/59).

- [setup.py: Open README with utf-8 encoding](https://github.com/arthurdejong/python-stdnum/pull/60/files).

### Solution

1. Go to [arthurdejong.org/python-stdnum/](https://arthurdejong.org/python-stdnum/) and find [python-stdnum-1.8.tar.gz](https://arthurdejong.org/python-stdnum/python-stdnum-1.8.tar.gz)
2. Download the Zip in a folder, rename it from `python-stdnum-1.8.tar.gz` to `python-stdnum-1.8.tar_.gz` (Just to avoid name collision).
3. Then create the following Python Script (in the same directory):

---

```py
import tarfile

def open_tarfile_function(tarfile_file_name):
    open_tarfile=tarfile.open("python-stdnum-1.8.tar_.gz")
    open_tarfile.extractall(path='stdnum')
    open_tarfile.close()

open_tarfile_function('data.tgz')
```

---

4. It will create a folder named stdnum, open it and then open `setup.py`, go to line 37 and modify from this:

---

```py
with open(os.path.join(base_dir, 'README'), 'r') as fp:
    long_description = fp.read()
```

To this:

```py
with open(os.path.join(base_dir, 'README'), 'rb') as fp:
    long_description = fp.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Save it.

5. Now in the same Directory run this code:

---

```py
import tarfile
import os.path

def make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
        tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.sep)

output_filename = "python-stdnum-1.8.tar.gz"
source_dir = "stdnum\python-stdnum-1.8"

make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir)
```

---

6. This will create file `python-stdnum-1.8.tar.gz` copy the **Absolute Path**
7. Go to your Python Environment and run:

---

```py
pip install D:\Odoo\Odoo_instance_one\python-stdnum-1.8.tar.gz
```

Obviously replace the Absolute Path with your absolute path.

Comment: Hi Federico, I am trying your solution but I'm stuck at step 3. Do I have to change something in that script? I get the following error message when I try to run it: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python-stdnum-1.8.tar_.gz'

Comment: @Nomad_King  Check better Step 2, **Download the Zip in a folder, rename it from python-stdnum-1.8.tar.gz to python-stdnum-1.8.tar_.gz**  Did you rename the folder adding the '_'  at the end?

Comment: This is only to avoid name collision, then in Step 5 you will output with the correct name **python-stdnum-1.8.tar.gz**  if you follow the step there it should be to change any of my code.

Answer (score 0):

First,you can use the online installation, use the command `pip install python-stdnum==1.8`.

Second,you can download whl file of python-stdnum from [here](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/dc/812bd538758f4b9b75e2acf5dee27207e1e05c2a24d06aa4d3f4f7f3a061/python_stdnum-1.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl).

For example download to `F:/file`.

Then use command `pip install F:/file/python_stdnum-1.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl` to install.

`python-stdnum 1.8` is the previous version, there is no corresponding whl file anymore.

In general, the previous version corresponds to the python version is relatively low, so if you use `pip install python-stdnum==1.8` to install, there may be problems, because your current python is 3.7, which is relatively new.

Comment: Hi August, that worked perfectly. The only thing is that the module still asks me for the version 1.8. I do not seem to find this version as a whl file type. the only file type for version 1.8 on pypi.org, is the source file type. Is the installation for this file type the same?

Comment: Hi,If you use source file,download [python-stdnum-1.8.tar.gz](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/ad/9388970542f82857ac2958b3eaddfad16caaf967cf8532e9486dedc69420/python-stdnum-1.8.tar.gz).Then unzip the file. First,use `python setup.py build`,second,use 
`python setup.py install`.

Comment: The second option with the install command, seemed to go well. However, there was a warning which tried to run a so called "install_lib" but couldn't install it. It gave the message: install_lib: 'build\lib' does not exist -- no python modules to install. Within my python module it still requires me the stdnum==1.8.

Comment: It seems that the problem is caused by the old version and it is no longer maintained. This also explains why there is no whl file for python-stdnum 1.8.

Comment: @August I found a solution, in case someone needs to use version 1.8. It has to do with Windows